# How to make a long-expodure photo

Tags: long-exposure, timelapse

How can i make a long-exposure image like this :
http://elliott.org/blog/30-worst-cities-for-traffic-in-america/

For that task, do i need a special camera or can i do it with andtoid app ?

Comment: This isn't a time-lapse -- it is a long exposure.

Comment: I edited the question now.

Comment: At this point, if the linked question doesn't answer yours and you can't find the answer elsewhere on the site, probably best to ask a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a timelapse photo, that is a long-exposure photo.  A long shutter speed was used. To avoid camera shake blur, the photographer most probably used a tripod or other form of support for the camera, rather than handholding, and may also have used a timer or cable release and/or mirror lock-up to prevent any jostling of the camera from the shutter button being pressed.  If something longer than 30 seconds was required, bulb mode was probably used on the camera.

In very low ambient light, getting exposures that are seconds or even minutes long is possible. If the light levels aren't low enough to get a shutter speed long enough to get the light trails you want, you can also consider adding a neutral density filter to the camera lens to decrease the amount of light entering the camera.

Answer (score 1):

There is no video on this page.  Just a single image.

This image was made using a long exposure.  Say 30 seconds or longer.

Comment: then please tell me about that image and how to create that type of photo

Comment: Tripod and a slow shutter speed.  Very easy to do in low light.